# Can't access to WEB-INF/folder/folder/file.jsp

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, web-inf

I'm developing a little servlet with eclipse on a Tomcat server.

From this servlet I want to include some jsp files, it works perfectly for the file

> WEB-INF/website/NewFile.jsp

But when I try to get a jsp file in

> /WEB-INF/website/common

I get the 404 not found exception.

I've some other files in the "common" folder and I can get access to them.

So I guess that eclipse doesn't find the jsp in this folder when it comes to compile them. 

I suppose that I have to somehow change the "jsp searching path" of the eclipse project but I don't know how to do

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```
/yourapp/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/resources/website/common/newfile.jsp
```

for

```
http://localhost:8080/yourapp/website/common/newfile.jsp
```

Often other `WEB-INF` folders are not available.

Comment: Doesn't work for me :/, I can access to the file /myapp/WEB-INF/website/common/file.json so for me the path is ok but the jsp files aren't included during the eclipse build

Comment: Servlet 3.0 specification only demands support for serve static files from META-INF/resources, if the META-INF/resources is inside of a jar file in the /WEB-INF/lib directory. Kotaw jsp files are inside web-inf/somefolde/somefolder

Comment: Spec said: `Except for static resources and jsps packaged in the meta-inf/resources of a jar` (http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf)

Comment: @Kotaw What server version?

Comment: Hm, wicked! What version is your web.xml (`<web-app version="3.0">`)?

Comment: No it's 3.1 see : <web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee                       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

Comment: Now it works but I don't understand why ... It's just the exact same code ... (meanwhile I tried Tomcat 7.0 and went back to 8.0)

Comment: No idea why it works now - i am confused. (btw:Tomcat7 has no support for servlet-3.1)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot access files under WEB-INF folder directly.Container will look for classes in WEB-INF/classes and jsp files under WEB-INF can be included by other JSP/servlets,but any browser requesting resources down there will get a 404 response

Comment: @Peter Rader read user question then my answer , then above link you send to me "Tomcat passes this requirement because it serves files from jar but not from WEB-INF/classes" I hope it will clear your doubt

Comment: The bug has been resolved as described. See, i am able to serve jsps and "any other browser requesting resources" via `WEB-INF/classes`.